# Pandas index iat

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I use pandas indexing iat but i found error

> TypeError: **call**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

My code is:

```
df['xyz'] = df.index ,date_format = "%m/%d/%Y" ,x=len(df.index),start = df.iat(1,2) ,end = df.iat(x,2),df.drop('xyz'),print(start) ,
print(end) ,x = int(datetime.strftime(df.max(axis=0),date_format)-datetime.strftime(df.min(axis=0),date_format)) and print(df) gives this value 
               incoming  xyz
2015-09-03      1061 2015-09-03
2015-09-04      1193 2015-09-04
2015-09-05       618 2015-09-05
2015-09-07      1246 2015-09-07
2015-09-08      1054 2015-09-08
2015-09-09      1030 2015-09-09 etc
```

but i found error in `start line = df.iat(1,2)` .

> TypeError: **call**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3
>   were given

.

Comment: Could you format your code properly? Use backticks (`) for in-text code and four preceding spaces separated from text by newlines for code blocks.

Comment: thank you i will try to format properly

Comment: Why are there commas in between variable assignments? Did you mean to put a newline? Also, comments in python should have a preceding hashtag (#).

Comment: there is no comma in original code but in formatting in stackoverflow put comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add `[]`, not `()` to [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
df.iat[1,2]
```

Also change `[1,2]` to `[1,1]`,  because there are only 2 columns and python count from `0`.

IIUC you need:

```
print (df)
            incoming
2015-09-03      1061
2015-09-04      1193
2015-09-05       618
2015-09-07      1246
2015-09-08      1054
2015-09-09      1030

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
start = df.index[0]
end = df.index[-1]

print(start)
2015-09-03 00:00:00
print(end)
2015-09-09 00:00:00

x = end - start
print (x)
6 days 00:00:00
x = int(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
print (x)
6
```

Comment: i already did but give IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 in the same line

Comment: Hmmm, `column` `2015-09-03, 2015-09-04` is not column, but `index`. If use `print df.columns` it return only `2` column names, because in your sample are only 2 columns..

Comment: i want to print start and end column

Comment: which column? `incoming`? or `xyz`? Or first element of index and last element of index?

Comment: start = df.iat(1,2),  incoming column. In this line why its give me error.

Comment: what i did here i create one more column xyz where i print all the dates because index column its not count the sunday that why i create xyz column and later i put zero on sunday day..

Comment: print (df)         incoming       xyz
2015-09-03      1061 2015-09-03
2015-09-04      1193 2015-09-04
2015-09-05       618 2015-09-05
2015-09-07      1246 2015-09-07
2015-09-08      1054 2015-09-08

Comment: click to empty mark in top left of my answer bellow `0`.